# Express.js retrieving info from external API and rendering to site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am kind of stuck on how to handle this solution.  The frameworks I'm currently working with is node.js and express.js with pug for views/rendering html.  What I am trying to do is render to a single page and use values from separate http get requests from different sites.  I want express/node to query the external api's and render a view that I will retrieve via ajax call from the client side javascript.  The ajax call using jquery from the client side I have figured out.  My issue is how to handle multiple external API calls and place the results into an object to render in my pug view.  I'm not sure what the best practice would be to execute this properly.  Do I create a model?  Also, how do I handle the asynchronous http gets?  Use promises?  I'm kind of new to node and javascript so I'm trying to see what the best conventions to use.
I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!!!!

apiInfoModel.js

```
var apiCallInfo = {
    apiInfo1: APIDATA
    apiInfo2: APIDATA2
    apiInfo3: APIDATA3
}
```

Should I have a function that I call that would return the APIDATA?

apiCalls.js

```
function getApiInfo1() {
    return http.get
}

function getApiInfo2() {
    return http.get
}

function getApiInfo3() {
    return http.get
}
```

apiInfoController.js

```
var apiInfo = require('./apiInfoModel')
var apiCalls = require('./apiCalls')
exports.apiInfo = function(req,res,next){
    apiInfo.apiInfo1 = apiCalls.getApiInfo1
    apiInfo.apiInfo2 = apiCalls.getApiInfo2
    apiInfo.apiInfo3 = apiCalls.getApiInfo3
    res.render('apiInfo',{apiInfo: apiInfo})
}
```

Comment: You may have to put the call for the apiInfo2 as a callback of the getApiInfo1 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comment by @Mauricio Noris Freire

apiCalls.js - Add `callback` parameters

```
function getApiInfo1(cb) {
    return cb(http.get)
}

function getApiInfo2(cb) {
    return cb(http.get)
}

function getApiInfo3(cb) {
    return cb(http.get)
}
```

apiInfoController.js - nest the callbacks to have access to all the results

```
var apiInfo = require('./apiInfoModel')
var apiCalls = require('./apiCalls')
exports.apiInfo = function(req,res,next){

    apiCalls.getApiInfo1(function(info1Result) {
        apiCalls.getApiInfo2(function(info2Result) {
            apiCalls.getApiInfo3(function(info3Result) {
                // now you have all 3 results
                apiInfoResult = {
                    apiInfo1: info1Result,
                    apiInfo2: info2Result,
                    apiInfo3: info3Result
                }
                res.render('apiInfo', { apiInfo: apiInfoResult })
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This nested structure is referred to as the `pyramid of doom` because it keeps growing with every asynchronous action you need to do. It can be improved by using a utility library like `async` https://www.npmjs.com/package/async:

```
    async.parallel( [
        apiCalls.getApiInfo1,
        apiCalls.getApiInfo2,
        apiCalls.getApiInfo3
    ], function(error, apiInfoResult) {
        apiInfoResult = {
            apiInfo1: info1Result,
            apiInfo2: info2Result,
            apiInfo3: info3Result
        }
        res.render('apiInfo', { apiInfo: apiInfoResult })
    });
```

But the currently recommended way is to use `Promises`. This is a new `API` introduced in `JavaScript` to handle this kind of situations. It's available in recent `NodeJS` versions. It removes the need for `callbacks`:

apiCalls.js - Return promises instead of using `callbacks` (the `fetch` library does this)

```
require('whatwg-fetch')

function getApiInfo1() {
    return fetch()
}

function getApiInfo2() {
    return fetch()
}

function getApiInfo3() {
    return fetch()
}
```

apiInfoController.js - Use `Promise.all`.

```
    const [
        apiInfo1, 
        apiInfo2, 
        apiInfo3
    ] = Promise.all([apiCalls.getApiInfo1, apiCalls.getApiInfo2, apiCalls.getApiInfo3]);

    apiInfoResult = { apiInfo1, apiInfo2, apiInfo3 }
    res.render('apiInfo', { apiInfo: apiInfoResult })
```

Comment: Thanks @morgh!  As far as how I'm creating objects, I'm always unsure if I'm doing it the conventional way vs hacking it together. I guess I question my "pattern"

Comment: Then you might want to check out this open source book series: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS . They use clean coding conventions that you should be able to learn from. Also the "async" book has more information about all the callback/promise stuff I mentioned.